# I can't access html element inside useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet

I want to generate itinerary control (table element) generated in `<RoutingMachine />`.
But I cannot access html element in `useEffect` because it still not exist.

```
const Routing = ({ pointA, pointB }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()

    const createLayer = () => {
        const instance = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(pointA.position.lat, pointA.position.lng),
                L.latLng(pointB.position.lat, pointB.position.lng)
            ],
            lineOptions: {
                styles: [{ color: "red", weight: 4 }]
            },
        });

        return instance;
    };

    const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(createLayer);

    useEffect(() => {
        let routeInfo = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
        console.log(routeInfo) // array with 0 elements
    }, []);

    return <RoutingMachine />

};
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (with `useRef()`):

```
const Routing = ({ pointA, pointB }) => {

    const dispatch = useDispatch()
    const mounted = useRef(true)

    const createLayer = () => {
        const instance = L.Routing.control({
            waypoints: [
                L.latLng(pointA.position.lat, pointA.position.lng),
                L.latLng(pointB.position.lat, pointB.position.lng)
            ],
            lineOptions: {
                styles: [{ color: "red", weight: 4 }]
            },
        });

        return instance;
    };

    const RoutingMachine = createControlComponent(createLayer);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (mounted.current) {
          let routeInfo = document.querySelectorAll('tr')
          console.log(routeInfo) // array with 0 elements
        }

        return () => {
          mounted.current = false;
        }
    }, [mounted]);

    return <RoutingMachine />

};
```

Comment: Still getting empty NodeList. It is not empty when use setTimeout, but I looking for better solution.

Comment: Did you try to add `mounted` as a `useEffect()` dependency? Also, try to log before the if statement and see if there is a case when the NodeList is populated.

Comment: I cannot see the rest of the code, but I see you're using React Leaflet. As I can see from the documentation: `React does not render Leaflet layers to the DOM, this rendering is done by Leaflet itself. React only renders an <div> element when rendering the MapContainer component and the contents of UI layers components.` You should check if this is a problem.

Comment: I didn't know that before, thanks

Comment: Ok, I can see the code now. It seems that is the problem with the way Leaflet behaves. I think you have to create a reference on a RoutingMachine component, or try to wrap it with a <div />, and place the ref on the <div />.

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59743050/react-leaflet-placing-map-control-components-outside-of-map) for a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can use references supported by leaflet, checkout this [Reference](https://react-leaflet.js.org/docs/start-introduction/#leaflet-elements-references)