# Add event handler to element in custom child component for MapContainer

Tags: react-leaflet-v3

I am using react-leaflet (*v3.2.5*) with leaflet (*v1.8.0*). We need pretty custom zoom buttons and one additional 'home' like button on the map, which look like this:

[image: Custom Controls]

So I am trying to create a custom controls component like this (`<FeatherIcon />` is another component from our codebase):

```
function MapControls() :JSX.Element {
    
    const map = useMap();


    return <div className="leaflet-top leaflet-right vertical-controls clickable">
        <span className="control-icon-box" onClick={() => { console.log('in', map); map.zoomIn();}}><FeatherIcons iconId='plus-circle' className="feather vertical-control-icon" /></span>
        <span className="control-icon-box" onClick={() => { map.zoomOut();}}><FeatherIcons iconId='minus-circle' className="feather vertical-control-icon" /></span>
        <span className="control-icon-box"><FeatherIcons iconId='target' className="feather vertical-control-icon" /></span>
    </div>
}
```

I want to use it like this

```
<MapContainer center={[buildingsData.geoCenter.y, buildingsData.geoCenter.x]} zoom={buildingsData.geoCenter.zoom} scrollWheelZoom={true}
    zoomControl={false} zoomDelta={0.5}>

    <!-- other stuff -->
    <MapControls />
</MapContainer>
```

But the click handler is not added in the `MapContainer` context (like [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65077309/2092322)).

Do I need to use something like

```
const minusRef = useRef(null);
useEffect(() => {
    function minusClick() { /* doing stuff */ }
    if (minusRef.current !== null) {
         minusRef.current.addEventListener('click', minusClick);
    }

    return () => {
        if (minusRef.current !== null) {
             minusRef.current.removeEventLister('click', minusClick);
        }
    }
}, [map]);
```

[This solution here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59454075/2092322) is not really clear to me:

> I am not sure how to achieve that using your approach where
> react-leaflet's wrapper ZoomControl is not a child of Map wrapper when
> you try to place it outside the Map wrapper.
>
> However, for a small control like the ZoomControl, an easy solution
> would be to create a custom Zoom component, identical to the original,
> construct it easily using the native css style and after accessing the
> map element, invoke the zoom in and out methods respectively.
>
> In the below example I use react-context to save the map element after
> the map loads:
>
> ````
>     const map = mapRef.current.leafletElement;
>     setMap(map);   }, [mapRef, setMap]); ```
>
> and then here use the map reference to make a custom Zoom component
> identical to the native (for css see the demo):
>
> ``` const Zoom = () => {   const { map } = useContext(Context);
>     // etc ```
> ````

Comment: What exactly you don't understand from the last solution? What it does is that because you cannot access the map reference outside of `MapContainer`, that means that in any component that is not a child of `MapContainer` you store it somewhere globally (here using `react-context`) and then you can access it. A demo of what you have so far would help anyways...

Comment: I don't know what this `setMap` thing is and I guess that I'd use a simple state in the wrapping component and pass the map object back to the `Zoom` component instead of using `useContext` (which I just don't know well enough).